# Why don't my Vue keyup event properties work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following code in Vue which is working for the click events but not or the keyboard events:

```
<span v-show="show" @click.prevent="backTo" @keyup.enter="backTo" @keyup.space="backTo">
```

I have the `backTo()` method set up to go to the previous page, but when I use the keyboard events it does nothing. When clicked it is working fine.

I placed an alert in the method to understand what it is doing, but on the keyboard event it does nothing and `onmouseclick` I get the alert.

Answer (score 1):

`span`s don't typically see keyboard events. Either change to a naturally editable element, or add `tabindex="0"` or add `contenteditable=true`

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  },
  methods: {
    backTo() {
      alert('got here!');
    },
    backToA() {
      alert('got here from anchor!');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span tabindex="0" @click.prevent="backTo" @keyup.enter="backTo" @keyup.space="backTo">Click on me to give me focus, then press space or enter</span>
  <br/>
  <a href="#" tabindex="0" @click.prevent="backToA" @keyup.enter="backToA" @keyup.space="backToA">Same thing in an anchor tag</a>

</div>
```

Comment: but what about the click event, where will that go, i cannot remove that, i can change span to div nut that still did not work

Comment: your code is incomplete, you removed the click event handler

Comment: @Neeza - the issue was keyboard events.  Edited to use the click code as-is, working as expected.

Comment: i changed the span to anchor tag and it failed on that instance, it does not work on the anchor tags, how can i fix that

Comment: fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dg5ra0fL/

Comment: @Neeza, I just ran the fiddle, and click and space/enter work as expected for me (in fairly current safari and chrome).  I also edited this answer to use an anchor tag, and it also worked as expected. If they are not working for you, maybe it has to do with your specific client setup.